# Is there a cross-platform way to get the webApps directory for Tomcat?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Let's say that you've got these environment variables set:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat9
```

How can you reliably locate the Tomcat webApps directory based on that?

I can parse the server.xml, find the appropriate Host element, and read the appBase property for that (let's say it's 'webApps'). How do I know which directory that webApps folder is relative to? On Ubuntu with a default installation, it would be /var/lib/tomcat{version}/webApps, but on Windows, Mac, or Amazon Linux it's going to be CATALINA_BASE/webApps.

Other than just switching based on the OS and handling Ubuntu specially (which feels very icky and unreliable), is there some way to inspect the Tomcat installation itself to determine this?

Comment: Need more info here.  are you trying to write a program to find where the webapps are located? If so, which language are you using? (please add the relevant tag(s))

Comment: I am trying to find where webapps are located. I'm writing the code in Java, but this is a conceptual question - assuming I were just poking around in an ssh session, how would I know, unambiguously, the absolute path to the webapps folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such (reliable) way: web apps do not need to have a representation in the file system *at all*. They can also be a war file that is unzipped to memory when running, but never to the file system. Those web files can also be located in arbitrary locations.

All in all, your question sounds like an [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364505) to me. You might want to ask a question about the underlying problem.

Comment: The Host element has an appBase property. That represents a folder on the disk. My question can be stated very simply: What folder is the appBase relative to?